# Matriz 4x4 ta ficando com 20 elementos

Tags: python, array, lista, matriz

Galera fiz um código em Python cujo exercicio pedia para fazer uma matriz 4x4 , mostrar a quantidade de elementos maiores que 10 e mostrar a matriz final.
Fiz e ficou tudo certo só que a matriz ta ficando com 20 elementos e não ta separando por colchetes a cada 4 elementos.
Aqui esta meu codigo

```
m = []
m1 = []
contadorp = 0
for i in range(4):
    m.append(int(input()))
    for j in range(4):
        m1.append(int(input()))
    if m[i] > 10 or m1[j] > 10 :
        contadorp = contadorp + 1
print('A quantidade de numeros maiores que 10 é ' , contadorp)
print(m,m1)
```

Comment: simples, o range começa em 0. logo: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. Basta tu colocar 3, assim ele terá 4 casas a partir do 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, você estava fazendo algumas coisas erradas, veja o meu código que fiz baseado no seu:

O que você fez não estava de fato sendo uma matriz, apenas a entrada de valores e depois a comparação.

Veja o que fiz:

Eu acumulo n elementos em `m1`, que seriam colunas, e depois deposito em `m`, que se tornariam em uma linha, repetindo esse processo dependendo de quantas linhas você quer.

Depois ao final eu uso outro for para saber quais são maiores que 10. Isso dava para fazer ainda no outro `for`, mas como você não utilizou uma variável no `input()` eu não alterei isso.

```
m = []
m1 = []
contadorp = 0
for i in range(4): # Linhas
    for j in range(4): # Colunas
        m1.append(int(input('Numero:'))) # Eu adiciono os valores dentro de m1
    m.append(m1) # E depois, após adicionar 4 números, eu deposito em "m"
    m1 = [] # Zero m1 para poder depositar outro valor quando o For recomeçar

for i in m: # I vai representar cada lista dentro de m
    for j in i: # J vai representar cada valor dentro de I
        if j > 10:
            contadorp = contadorp + 1 # Faço a comparação
print('A quantidade de números maiores que 10 é ' , contadorp) # Dou o resultado
print(m)
```

**saída:**

```
>>> Numero:1
>>> Numero:2
>>> Numero:3
>>> Numero:4
>>> Numero:5
>>> Numero:6
>>> Numero:7
>>> Numero:8
>>> Numero:9
>>> Numero:10
>>> Numero:11
>>> Numero:12
>>> Numero:13
>>> Numero:14
>>> Numero:15
>>> Numero:16
>>> A quantidade de numeros maiores que 10 é  6
>>> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra maneira (não sei se mais elegante) de se obter o que deseja:

```
contador = 0
def foo(x):
  global contador
  if x > 10:
     contador += 1
  return x
matriz = [[ foo(int(input())) for i in range(4)] for i in range(4)]
print('A quantidade de numeros maiores que 10 é', contador)
print(matriz)
```

Para definir a matriz pode-se usar [list-comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), e ao invés de definir um valor pra cada elemento, eu chamo uma função passando como parâmetro o input, e se o valor for > 10 eu incremento +1 na variável global contador

Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/INku)

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, você deseja montar e exibir uma matriz quadrada de ordem `4`, ou seja, matriz quadrada `"4 x 4"`, além de mostrar a quantidade de elementos que possuem valores maiores que `10`.

Pois bem, para resolver esta questão podemos utilizar um algoritmo que seja capaz de montar **apenas** matrizes quadradas de ordem `"4 x 4"` ou utilizar um algoritmo que seja capaz de montar **quaisquer** matrizes de ordem `"m x n"` (m = linhas e n = colunas).

Como a minha intenção é mostrar, de forma mais abrangente, a montagem de qualquer matriz, então, poderemos utilizar o seguinte algoritmo abaixo. Pois, este será capaz de montar quaisquer matrizes de ordem `"m x n"`.

Como no seu caso a matriz sempre será quadrada, isto é `m = n`, isso implica que a quantidade de linhas é igual a quantidade de colunas.

```
import numpy as np

m = int(input('Digite o número de linhas: '))
n = int(input('Digite o número de colunas: '))

cont = 0
matrizTemp = list()
for c in range(1, m + 1):
    linha = list()
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        while True:
            try:
                valor = int(input(f'Digite o {i}º elemento de {c}ª linha: '))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas inteiros!\033[m')
        if valor > 10:
            cont += 1
        linha.append(valor)
    matrizTemp.append(linha)

# Exibindo a matriz e suas dimensões.
matriz = np.array(matrizTemp)
print(f'\033[32mA matriz gerada é:\n{matriz}')
print(f'A quantidade de elementos maiores que 10 é: {cont}\033[m')
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/hnkqmfhp-solkarped) o funcionamento do algoritmo.

Observe que quando executamos o algoritmo recebemos a seguinte mensagem; `Digite o número de linhas`. Neste momento devemos inserir o número de `linhas` que desejamos que a matriz tenha e pressionar enter. Posteriormente recebemos a segunda mensagem; `Digite o número de colunas`. Neste momento devemos inserir o número de `colunas` que desejamos que a matriz tenha e pressionar enter.

Depois disso devemos inserir cada um dos elementos da matriz. Durante a inserção de cada elemento da matriz um bloco `if` verifica se cada valor inserido é maior que `10`. Caso positivo, é acumulada a quantidade de valores maiores que `10` na variável contadora `cont`.

Ao término da inserção dos valores o algoritmo montará e exibirá a matriz e também, a quantidade de elementos cujos valores sejam maiores que `10`.

**Exemplo**

Imagine que queremos criar uma matriz `4 x 4` que tenha os seguintes valores:

```
1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 10, 11, 3, 12, 16, 5, 7, 8, 14, 15, 20
```

Quando executamos este código recebemos a mensagem: `digite o número de linhas:`. Neste momento devemos digitar o número **4** e pressionar `enter`. Em seguida, recebemos a segunda mensagem: `Digite o número de colunas:`. Neste momento devemos digitar novamente o número **4** e pressionar `enter`. Depois recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite o 1º elemento da 1ª linha:`. Neste momento devemos digitar o primeiro elemento, que no caso do exemplo sugerido é **1**. Posteriormente somos solicitados para digitar o próximo valor e, neste momento, devemos inserir o próximo valor.

Depois de termos inserido todos os valores sugeridos no exemplo sugerido o script irá montar uma matriz quadrada de ordem `4 x 4` com todos os valores digitados e, também, irá mostrar a quantidade de termos que possuem valores maiores que `10`.

Posteriormente o script irá mostrar as seguintes saídas:

```
A matriz gerada é:
[[ 1  2  4  6]
 [ 9 10 11  3]
 [12 16  5  7]
 [ 8 14 15 20]]
A quantidade de elementos maiores que 10 é: 6
```

Perceba que o script exibirá a montagem da matriz quadrada de ordem `4 x 4`, além de exibir a quantidade de elementos que possuem valores **maiores** que `10`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar list comprehension aninhada:

```
m = [[ input('Número') for i in range(4)] for x in range(4)]
```

Entrada dos dados manualmente:

```
Número 1
Número 2
Número 3
Número 4
Número 5
Número 6
Número 7
Número 8
Número 9
Número 10
Número 11
Número 12
Número 13
Número 14
Número 15
Número 16
```

Mostrando a matriz gerada:

```
print(m)
[['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['5', '6', '7', '8'], ['9', '10', '11', '12'], ['13', '14', '15', '16']]
```

Verificando os números maiores que 10:

```
resultado = len([item for sublista in m for item in sublista if int(item) > 10])
print(f'Dentro da matriz existem {resultado} números maiores que 10')
```

Saída:

```
Dentro da matriz existem 6 números maiores que 10
```

Código completo:

```
m = [[ input('Número') for i in range(4)] for x in range(4)]
print(m)
resultado = len([item for sublista in m for item in sublista if int(item) > 10])
print(f'Dentro da matriz existem {resultado} números maiores que 10')
```